# How to hide buttons in iOS when webview has finished loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, button, uiwebview

I am not sure why is this set of codes not working to hide iphone buttons as soon as the webview has loaded?

```
GoogleMap_BetaViewController.h

@interface GoogleMap_BetaViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
 IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
 UIButton *retrieveReminder;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *retrieveReminder;
- (IBAction) RetrieveReminder:(id)sender;
@end

testController.m

@implementation GoogleMap_BetaViewController
@synthesize webView,retrieveReminder;
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
 [retrieveReminder setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: Check if retrieveReminder is correctly hooked to the correct IB item.

Comment: something is weird... it show i am hook to the caps RetrieveReminder?

why is that so? thought RetrieveReminder is just a method?

Comment: retrieveReminder is an IBOutlet to a UIButton that is supposed to be hooked to an element in your .xib. RetrieveReminder is your IBAction method. Take note of the uppercase and lowercase starting letter. Make sure that your retrieveReminder is hooked correctly to the UIButton you want to hide in the .xib file.

Comment: however, when i drag and drop from the UIButton to the controller class.. i can only see RetrieveReminder, there is not a option for me to choose retrieveReminder.. why is that so? thanks

Comment: You have to link your UIButton to File's Owner entry retrieveReminder.

Comment: gosh, think i am linking it wrongly... i do not have retrieveReminder in file's owner. i only have them in the my controller class under outlets section.. but i cant link those to my buttons

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan, have you connect UIWebViewDelegate properly ? Have you check that WebViwDidFinishLoad get called everytime.

Comment: hi yeah the method get called everytime... i think is the linking of the buttons problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the webFiview delegate to self and then use its delegate method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    button.hidden = YES;
}
```

Have you tried to set the delegate of the webview in the IB? That is a must, as you are using its delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

As commented in response above, make sure that you are going from Files Owner to the Button and not the Button to Files Owner (which will show you IBActions).  Also, once you get the right variable hooked up, make sure you are using self.retrieveReminder so that you are accessing the variable through the getters/setters which is what the IBOutlet is hooked up to.

Answer (score 0):

Based on our discussion in the comments, I guess you are linking it wrongly. Take a look at this video for a visual tutorial on linking IBOutlets. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-EpTGOcC0Jw